# How long does it take for spearmint leaves to regrow?

Tags: leaves, harvesting, mint

I just took a bunch of spearmint leaves, so when will they grow back?
I did some research and a timeframe wasn’t given.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, the individual leaves will not grow back. The plant in its entirety will continue to grow, and new growth will appear, in various places:

1. At the tips of the existing stems, in pairs, effectively making the stems longer.
2. In the axils, i.e. where a leaf is connected to a stem. This will happen when the tip of a stem is cut off.
3. New shots from the roots will come up.

The overall growth rate will depend on environmental factors, like the season, temperatures, available water and nutrients.

How quickly a plant can regrow harvested leaf mass will depend on the previously mentioned factors and the percentage of lost leaves. A full bush will not be influenced by the loss of a few leaves, but the more is harvested, the less leaf mass will remain for photosynthesis and the more energy has to be drawn from the plant’s reserves.

Conclusion:
A simple answer along the lines of “it will regrow in X days” is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, mint grows very fast, so I wouldn't worry too much unless you took off almost all its leaves.

A store-bought mint plant took 3-4 weeks to roughly double in size with regular watering and moderate shade.

Comment: but how long does it take to grow?